# How to have pointer events apply on the circle inside the path?

Tags: html, css, svg, whitespace, removing-whitespace

How would that be fixed in the code so that the white space is removed?

https://jsfiddle.net/k14svx2q/

How would I be able to remove the white space from the code?

Is there a way to fix or adjust that so there is no white space?

Pointer events should only apply on the "circle" inside the path.

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fadeInExit 2s forwards 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit:hover .exitHover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" fill="red" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
```

I was recommended to do this:

```
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="144" fill="transparent" />
```

But that did not work: https://jsfiddle.net/vnghab8k/

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fadeInExit 2s forwards 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit:hover .exitHover {
  fill: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>

            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="144" fill="transparent" />
            <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" fill="red" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
```

Comment: So you want the pointer events to only apply on the "circle" inside that path? To do so, you'd need to actually have a <circle cx=0 cy=0 r=144 fill=transparent /> in there, before the <path> and then you can do `circle:hover + .exitHover { fill: green; }` (and place the `cursor` rule on that <circle> too).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by whitespace? Looks good to me?

Comment: That didn't work in the code, what you suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/vnghab8k/ <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="144" fill="transparent" /> 
@Kaiido knows what I am referring to.

Comment: Because you only applied half of my suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/8egnd2ut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to make the area outside the circle non-hoverable is to clip the parent into a circle using clip-path:

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fadeInExit 2s forwards 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
   clip-path: circle(50%);
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit:hover .exitHover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path class="exitHover" d="m-143 0a143 143 0 1 1 286 0 143 143 0 0 1 -286 0m128-112a113 113 0 0 0 -97 97h97zm-97 127a113 113 0 0 0 97 97v-97zm127 97a113 113 0 0 0 97 -97h-97zm97-127a113 113 0 0 0 -97 -97v97z" transform="rotate(45)" fill="red" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
```

Comment: How come the hover is not working in here? https://jsfiddle.net/hnba7z0d/